# Symfony2 and sqlite, SQLSTATE[HY000] caught

Tags: sqlite, symfony

I'm trying to use sqlite3 with symfony2.
This is my database configuration in app/config/parameters.yml

```
parameters:
database_driver: pdo_sqlite
database_host: 127.0.0.1
database_port: null
database_name: librarian
database_user: root
database_password: null
database_path: librarian
```

And my app/config/config.yml

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   %database_driver%
    host:     %database_host%
    port:     %database_port%
    dbname:   %database_name%
    user:     %database_user%
    password: %database_password%
    charset:  UTF8
    path: %kernel.root_dir%/%database_path%.db

orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
    auto_mapping: true
```

I've created a simple table to do some test. This table have an integer auto-increment 'id' field, a 'link' text field and a 'index' integer field.

The controller is simple :

```
class testController extends Controller {

  public function indexAction() {
    $issue = new Issue();
    $issue->setIndex(0);
    $issue->setLink(array('http://example.com'));

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($issue);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->render('TestLibrarianBundle:Test:index.html.twig');
  }
}
```

When I try to get execute the request by calling this controller, I got the following error:

```
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException: "An exception  occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO issue (index, link) VALUES (?, ?)':

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "index": syntax error" at /.../.../vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php line 47
```

Any hint on how to solve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you name a field index if it's a sqlite keyword?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `INDEX` is an [SQL keyword](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).

If you cannot configure your ORM to escape names properly (writing them as `"index"` instead), you have to change the field name to something else.

Comment: Ok thanks. I use doctrine2. I thought that it was obvious that such keywords were properly escaped...